# Getting the response of an instagram url

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I am trying to integrate a third party application. The procedure is as follows:

1. I have the url of the third party (login required)
2. I have to paste this in the browser. The result of this will be an url in the browser.

For example: the url stands like this:

1. `https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=157c0c51ef58435893a50e0430b5f53b&redirect_uri=http://www.hashgurus.com/redirect.aspx&response_type=code&scope=likes+basic+comments+relationships`
2. Now when I paste this url in the browser (login required, once logged in cookie is set) it redirects to another url.

Example: `hashgurus.com/redirectd.aspx?code=abcdedf`. The output of this url is a string.

Now I want to programatically emulate this in console application. My code:

```
HttpWebRequest myReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(link);

WebResponse webresponse =  myReq.GetResponse();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(webresponse.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
string result = sr.ReadToEnd();
sr.Close();
```

But the variable result holds some other html (the login page). Instead I expected the response of this url `hashgurus.com/redirectd.aspx?code=abcdedf`.

When i do everything manually in the browser, everything happens smoothly because the cookie is set.  but programtically it doesnot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You receiving different html source code, because of automatic redirections done by `HttpWebRequest`. You need first disable auto redirection. It can be done using following code:

```
HttpWebRequest myReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(link);
myReq.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
```

[Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.allowautoredirect(v=vs.110).aspx)

After that, follow all steps provided by api. For better understanding of whole path use sniffing tools like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler).

Comment: EHh, despite of this you also consider using: cookies, headers and handle proper encoding (is any exists). I suggest you use Fiddler or any other tool for web debugging and see what's happening underhood.

Comment: @Venkat: As far as I understood your question, you wanted to do something on Instagram using first link. You expected response from the page `hashgurus.com/redirectd.aspx?code=abcdedf`, but you are receiving login page, right? If so, you need to authentiacte your request.

Comment: exactly!!! the first link is instagram page, this will redirect to a redirect url that is hashgurus.com/redirect.aspx. The output of this is what i want. But I get the instagram login page url.

Comment: @Venkat: It can't happen the way you think. When you paste link above to web borowser, browser automatically authenticates you using stored cookie (cookie which was saved when you login to Instagram) and redirects to expected website. Your implementation does know nothing about your cookie so you have two options: copy cookie value and pass it during requesting or authenticate manually and obtain new cookie for application (secound option is more professional).

Comment: Its a instagram cookie. How will I have access to it? I dont think it is possible. I have to open this in a web browser and do the task.